# Property Grid Custom Editor

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid

I have a custom form Names "Form1" that I want to open through propertygrid control.

[image: I want to make it like this]
[image]

Code here

```
[CategoryAttribute("Extended Properties"),
        EditorAttribute(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Form1), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
        [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
        public string Path { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a class that inherits from `UITypeEditor` who's job will be to display `Form1`. This type is what goes into the `EditorAttribute` (not `Form1`). The sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.iwindowsformseditorservice.aspx) is more or less what you need to implement. Basically, you override `GetEditorStyle` to return `UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal` and override `EditValue` to call `IWindowsFormsEditorService.ShowDialog` on an instance of your form.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. I am giving you vote up but I will try it later if it works I will mark your answer as right answer
Thank you again